# $(this) toggleClass not working with .each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have some divs called archbar2 and I want to change it using .each loop but I have no reaction from javascript side. Everything is working before because alerts works great. Why my class is not changing?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var aktywator=0;
    var punkty = 333;
    if(punkty>=10 && punkty<300) aktywator = 0;
    if(punkty>=300 && punkty<800) aktywator = 1;
    if(punkty>=800 && punkty<2000) aktywator = 2;
    if(punkty>=2000 && punkty<5000) aktywator = 3;
    if(punkty>=5000 && punkty<10000) aktywator = 4;
    if(punkty>=10000) aktywator = 5;
    alert(aktywator);
    $('.archbar2').each(function(id) {
        
        if(aktywator==id)
        {
            alert("id=" + id + " aktywator=" + aktywator);
            $(this).toggleClass("archbar");
        }
    })

});
```

```css
.archbar
{
 width: 50vw;
 height: 13vw;
 background-color: #1274B2;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 0.5vw;
 margin-top: 2vw;
 position: relative;
}

.archbar2
{
 width: 50vw;
 height: 13vw;
 background-color: rgba(50,50,50,1);
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 0.5vw;
 margin-top: 2vw;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
<div class="archbar2">

</div>
</center>

<center>
<div class="archbar2">

</div>
</center>

<center>
<div class="archbar2">
</div>
</center>
```

Please look at this example and tell me why it can not run correctly.
Greatings

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: I want to change class "archbar2" to "archbar"...  $(this).toggleClass("archbar") is not working...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as it should, but probably not the way you want it to.

> I want to change class `archbar2` to `archbar`...
>   `$(this).toggleClass("archbar")` is not working.

If you want to switch between to classes, you'd have to use `$.toggleClass()` with the existing class name as an argument as well as the new class name.

```
$(this).toggleClass("archbar").toggleClass("archbar2");
```

Which will toggle both the classes to the element.

See the jQuery documentation of [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) which states:

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of
>   matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the
>   value of the state argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is getting added, the problem is the styles from `archbar2`  are overriding any styles that are gained by `archbar` class. Define the `archbar` class with a [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and it will override `archbar2`.

In this case you could define your `archbar` class as `div.archbar`, note though this would limit the style to only div's with class archbar

```
div.archbar
{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 13vw;
    background-color: #1274B2;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5vw;
    margin-top: 2vw;
    position: relative;
}
```

If you wanted to switch the classes you would just remove the old class and add the new one

```
$(".archbar2").removeClass("archbar2").addClass("archbar");
//Or just pass both classes to toggleClass if you are going to
//be toggling between both.
$(".archbar2").toggleClass("archbar2 archbar");
```

---

Higher Specificity demo

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var aktywator=0;
    var punkty = 333;
    if(punkty>=10 && punkty<300) aktywator = 0;
    if(punkty>=300 && punkty<800) aktywator = 1;
    if(punkty>=800 && punkty<2000) aktywator = 2;
    if(punkty>=2000 && punkty<5000) aktywator = 3;
    if(punkty>=5000 && punkty<10000) aktywator = 4;
    if(punkty>=10000) aktywator = 5;
    alert(aktywator);
    $('.archbar2').each(function(id) {
        
        if(aktywator==id)
        {
            alert("id=" + id + " aktywator=" + aktywator);
            $(this).toggleClass("archbar");
        }
    })

});
```

```css
div.archbar
{
 width: 50vw;
 height: 13vw;
 background-color: #1274B2;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 0.5vw;
 margin-top: 2vw;
 position: relative;
}

.archbar2
{
 width: 50vw;
 height: 13vw;
 background-color: rgba(50,50,50,1);
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 0.5vw;
 margin-top: 2vw;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
<div class="archbar2">

</div>
</center>

<center>
<div class="archbar2">

</div>
</center>

<center>
<div class="archbar2">
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [.toggleClass() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), a class passed in as argument will be:

- **added** to the element **if that element doesn't have that class**.
- **removed** from the element **if that element has that class**.

Thus you must pass both `archbar` and `archbar2` as parameter to `.toggleClass()` so that it will be added or removed based on whether it's present or not on the element.

```
$(this).toggleClass("archbar archbar2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `toggleClass("archbar")` to `toggleClass("archbar2 archbar")`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var aktywator=0;
    var punkty = 333;
    if(punkty>=10 && punkty<300) aktywator = 0;
    if(punkty>=300 && punkty<800) aktywator = 1;
    if(punkty>=800 && punkty<2000) aktywator = 2;
    if(punkty>=2000 && punkty<5000) aktywator = 3;
    if(punkty>=5000 && punkty<10000) aktywator = 4;
    if(punkty>=10000) aktywator = 5;
    //alert(aktywator);
    $('.archbar2').each(function(id) {
        
        if(aktywator==id)
        {
            //alert("id=" + id + " aktywator=" + aktywator);
            $(this).toggleClass("archbar2 archbar");
        }
    })

});
```

```css
.archbar
{
 width: 50vw;
 height: 13vw;
 background-color: #1274B2;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 0.5vw;
 margin-top: 2vw;
 position: relative;
}

.archbar2
{
 width: 50vw;
 height: 13vw;
 background-color: rgba(50,50,50,1);
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 0.5vw;
 margin-top: 2vw;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
<div class="archbar2">

</div>
</center>

<center>
<div class="archbar2">

</div>
</center>

<center>
<div class="archbar2">
</div>
</center>
```